# SSH XForwarding fails - xauth bad display name

Tags: ssh, xforwarding, xauth

I'm trying to setup XForwarding over ssh, but it fails. The same result happens whether I use the argument -X or -Y for ssh. The error I get.

```
a@ASUS-N53SM:~$ ssh -X -p 6623 pinker@192.168.0.200
pinker@192.168.0.200's password: 
Last login: Sun Feb  2 18:42:08 2014 from 192.168.0.201
/usr/bin/xauth: (stdin):1:  bad display name "pinker-server:10.0" in "remove" command
/usr/bin/xauth: (stdin):2:  bad display name "pinker-server:10.0" in "add" command
xdpyinfo:  unable to open display "pinker-server:10.0".
```

In the client file ~/.ssh/config

```
ForwardX11 yes
```

In the client file /etc/ssh/ssh_config (comments removed).

```
Host *
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes 
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

In the server file /etc/ssh/sshd_config (comments removed).

```
Port 6623
Port 6624
Port 6625
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
UsePAM yes
X11UseLocalhost no
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

I found this similar [Question](https://superuser.com/questions/126521/xauth-error-with-ssh-x-forwarding), but none of the answers work.

**UPDATE:**

On the server, I added to the file /etc/hosts.

```
127.0.0.1       pinker-server
```

On the server, I installed the package `xbase-clients`. On the ssh connection `echo $DISPLAY` outputs `:0.0`.

Now I'm getting a new error.

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
xdpyinfo:  unable to open display "pinker-server:10.0".
```

Answer (score 8):

This error occurs when the remote machine doesn't know it's own hostname, or has an incorrect hostname associated with 127.0.1.1 (NOTE: Not 127.0.0.1 which should always resolve to localhost).

To correct it, ensure that the entry in /etc/hosts for 127.0.1.1 matches the machine's FQDN and short hostname.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the case for me on my OpenBSD 5.9 (-current) desktop.

Comment: a good clue that this is the case, is when "xauth list" shows two difference hostnames.
root@sdi-playout:~# xauth list
ubuntu-NANOCOM-BT/unix:1  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ...
sdi-playout/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1   ...

Comment: Thanks! This helped me solve the X-forwarding failure for my VPS.

Answer (score 7):

On the remote machine, edit the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Change `X11UseLocalhost` to yes.

Source http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php?topic=109487.0

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 6):

Any time I run into an SSH issue I almost immediately re-run the command with more verbose messaging enabled. I like to use this technique to collect the log file on the server I'm running `ssh` from. If you need to get more details simply add more `-v` switches (the maximum is 3).

```
$ ssh -v user@remoteserver |& tee /path/to/sshv1.log
-or-
$ ssh -vv user@remoteserver |& tee /path/to/sshv2.log
```

#### X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.

This message is almost always indicative of a permissions problem with your `.Xauthority` file. You can either move the existing one out of the way temporarily or attempt to fix its ownership & permissions.

```
$ chown user:group ~/.Xauthority
$ chmod 0600 ~/.Xauthority
```

If the issue isn't resolved by either of these operations then you can attempt to diagnose the `xauth` magic cookies themselves.

*as local user running ssh*

```
$ xauth list
localhost/unix:13 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 c77169a6fa8139ea36f538e1c72e1b98
```

*as pinker on server*

```
$ xauth
Using authority file /home/pinker/.Xauthority
```

Then add the key manually:

```
xauth> add localhost/unix:13 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 c77169a6fa8139ea36f538e1c72e1b98
```

#### References

- [Linux X11 Connection Rejected Because of Wrong Authentication Error and Solution](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/x11-connection-rejected-because-of-wrong-authentication/)

Answer (score 2):

I got most of this information from http://openvz.org/X_inside_VE#X_forwarding

**Verify X in SSH**

After login via SSH, verify that X forwarding is working by looking for the DISPLAY environmental variable:

`echo $DISPLAY`

The answer should be something like `localhost:8.0`

**Make sure sshd allows X forwarding**

Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and make sure it has `X11Forwarding yes`

If not, edit or add the line with X11Fordwarding then restart sshd:

`service sshd restart` (`/etc/init.d/sshd restart` is using CentOS 5)

Then log out and in again

**Make sure xauth is set up**

Make sure the xauth package has been installed.  In Debian, this is part of the `xbase-clients` package.

**It's still not working**

In the question I am answering, the error message is this: `/usr/bin/xauth: (stdin):1:  bad display name "pinker-server:10.0" in "remove" command`

One possible solution, suggested below, is making sure the relevant line in `sshd_config` looks like this:

```
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

Comment: It looks like we might be getting closer to the solution? I have updated the info above. Thank you.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to add a hostname to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Bumped into this problem after Gentoo upgrade. This page is the first google result for 'add display name unix in add command'. None of the solutions described here helped. The workaround is written in the debian bug description (second link in the fore-mentioned google search page):

```
sethostname any-name-here
```

after execution of 'sethostname vvk' I  can log in with X-forwarding as before. This answer is typed from the browser which is being run in the very first proper shell logged in on remote server.

Answer (score 0):

For me works like a charm
sshd_config

```
    Protocol 2
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
KerberosAuthentication yes
KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
KerberosTicketCleanup yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
X11UseLocalhost yes
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes      # Default for new installations.
Banner /etc/issue.net
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
Ciphers aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,arcfour256
MACs hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
```

ssh_config

```
Host *
   ForwardX11trusted yes
   GSSAPIAuthentication yes
   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
```

And use

```
ssh -X remotehost
```

of course Xorg server must be installed full(using groupinstall,good idea)

Comment: typical sshd config, nothing special.