# SSH - How to make X applications run on client?

Tags: ssh, xorg, openssh, xforwarding

I have the reverse problem that most people seem to be having. If I start an X application while logged into ssh, it displays on the server(host) machine instead of the client(local). This is the command I use

```
$ ssh -X -p 6623 pinker@192.168.0.200
```

My $DISPLAY variable appears correct on the client.

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

I want X applications from the server to display locally on the client (the machine I'm physically at). I don't know what is causing this.

Comment: What are you using for your ssh command? (i.e. what flags?)

Comment: Is the "server machine" the machine you are typing the command at (the computer in front of you) or the machine you are logged in to? Since X uses reverse terminology for client/server than the rest of the world, it's ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit my post.

Comment: What is $DISPLAY set to when you are logged in to the server?  Also, the guidelines we're give you at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112217/ssh-xforwarding-fails-xauth-bad-display-name should help here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the sake of this conversation lets say there are 2 machines named `lappy` and `remotey`. The `lappy` system is where you'd be running your `ssh` commands from. The system you're connecting to is `remotey`.

#### 1. Display GUIs from remotey on lappy

```
        lappy               .-,(  ),-.    
           __  _         .-(          )-.          remotey 
          [__]|=|  ---->(    network     )------> ____   __ 
          /::/|_|        '-(          ).-'       |    | |==|
                             '-.( ).-'           |____| |  |
                                                 /::::/ |__|

      NOTE: on lappy, `ssh` to remotey, run GUI, see GUI on lappy
```

Your shell's configuration files are likely setting the environment variable `DISPLAY=:0`. You can grep for this like so:

```
 $ grep DISPLAY $HOME/{.bash*,.profile*}
```

If that doesn't return anything back then the system you're logging into is probably the culprit. Take a peek in this directory as well.

```
 $ grep DISPLAY /etc/profile.d/* /etc/bash*
```

If you'd rather just leave this be you can override this behavior by instructing `ssh` to redirect X traffic back to your client system, like so:

```
$ ssh -X user@remoteserver
```

#### Example

Here I have a remote server that has `$DISPLAY` getting set to `:0` similar to yours.

```
$ ssh -X skinner "echo $DISPLAY"
:0
```

But no matter, I can still invoke X applications and have them remote displayed to my system that's doing the `ssh` commands. I don't even have to login, I can simply run GUI's directly like so:

```
$ ssh -X skinner xeyes
```

As a bonus tip you'll probably  want to change which ciphers are being used, to help improve the performance of your X11 traffic as it passes over your SSH tunnel.

```
$ ssh -c arcfour,blowfish-cbc -X skinner xeyes
```

#### 2. Displaying GUIs on remotey

```
        lappy               .-,(  ),-.    
           __  _         .-(          )-.          remotey 
          [__]|=|  ---->(    network     )------> ____   __ 
          /::/|_|        '-(          ).-'       |    | |==|
                             '-.( ).-'           |____| |  |
                                                 /::::/ |__|

      NOTE: on lappy, `ssh` to remotey, run GUI, see GUI on remotey
```

If you're SSH'ing into `remotey` from `lappy` but would like to keep the GUIs from being displayed on `lappy`, then simply drop the `-X` switch from your `ssh` invoke.

```
$ ssh -p 6623 pinker@192.168.0.200
```

#### 3. Eliminating $HOME/.ssh/config

Often times a user's `$HOME/.ssh` directory can introduce unknowns as to what's going on. You can temporarily silence the use of the `config` file in this directory like so when performing tests.

```
$ ssh -F /dev/null -p 6623 pinker@192.168.0.200
```

#### 4. Eliminating remote shell's configs

You can use the following test to temporarily disable the shell's configuration files on `remotey` like so:

```
$ ssh -t -X -p 6623 pinker@192.168.0.200 "bash --norc --noprofile"
```

With the above, none of the setup should be getting sourced into this Bash shell, so you should be able to either set `DISPLAY=:0` and then display GUIs to remotey's desktop.

You can use the following trick to help isolate the issue, by first removing `--noprofile` and trying this command:

```
$ ssh -t -X -p 6623 pinker@192.168.0.200 "bash --norc"
```

Then followed by this command:

```
$ ssh -t -X -p 6623 pinker@192.168.0.200 "bash --noprofile"
```

The first version will tell you if the problem lies in your `/etc/bashrc` & `$HOME/.bashrc` chain of configuration files, while the second version will tell you if the problem lies in the `$HOME/.bash_profile` configuration file.

Comment: Hi slm. Your answer works, but I'm trying to get the applications to run "while logged into ssh". I really appreciate your tips. Thank you.

Comment: I want to 1) log into ssh 2) type xclock 3) see the xclock display in front of me. Instead the 3) is xclock appearing on host computer.

Comment: Host is the computer running sshd

Comment: @Rucent88 - very interesting, so if you drop the `-X` switch the GUIs are still being displayed on what I'm calling `lappy`? Is there any `$HOME/.ssh/config` file present?

Comment: I'm sorry, but no. You're getting it backward. All GUI's are being displayed on what you call remotey. I'm using the term HOST in proper terminology with the ssh manpage. Your post is very informative, but you've misunderstood what I wrote.

Comment: The only time I can get GUI to display on "lappy" is when I give it a specific application name at the end of ssh, like this `$ ssh -X -p 6623 pinker@192.168.0.200 firefox`

Comment: @Rucent88 - I just wanted to make sure I understand what you're trying to do, thanks for clarifying it, I think I understand your issue now. Given it works for the above command your issue is likely a stray command in either your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, assuming you're using bash as your shell. Does this command also work? `echo "firefox" | ssh -X -p 6623 pinker@192.168.0.200`?

Comment: Yes, the last command you put works to display GUI  locally (lappy).

Comment: @Rucent88 - yes. But the file `~/.bashrc` begins it's sourcing from `/etc/bashrc`, typically. So look at that file first, and follow things fro mthat file. There's a stray line that's setting something up that's the cause of your issue.

Comment: I found the problem in my ~/.bashrc file. I don't remember putting this in the file, but everything started working as expected when I removed the line `DISPLAY=":0.0"; export DISPLAY`

Comment: @Rucent88 - Terrific! It's always something simple one you tear it down. The commands I provided at the top should have found those errant lines: `grep DISPLAY $HOME/{.bash*,.profile*}`. Did that not find these lines?

Comment: There was quite a bit of miscommunication that happened our exchange, but thankfully now it's resolved. I'll need to remember that Host=sshd and Local=ssh. :D I appreciate all your help.

Comment: @Rucent88 - Expressing the situation w/ the correct terminology and in one that others understand is much of what I do here 8-). Different topic, I notice you had a couple of other Q's were those ever resolved to your satisfaction? If so can you accept them or make a not saying they're still open? - http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/49277/rucent88.

Comment: Very belatedly, your example `$ ssh -X skinner "echo $DISPLAY"` that returns `:0` is doing so because `$DISPLAY` is evaluated before the `ssh` is executed. I would have expected a value of something like `:10` for an `ssh -X` connection

Answer (score 2):

The key problem here is the `:0` on the last line:

```
$ ssh -X -p 6623 pinker@192.168.0.200
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

That suggests that something on the ssh-server is overriding your `DISPLAY` environment variable after sshd sets it. Since you happen to have an X server running there on display `:0`, any requests that X clients do on that computer are going to the local (i.e. the ssh-server) X server. If you ran the ssh-server X server (sic!) on a different display, you would get

```
$ xclock
Error: Can't open display: :1
```

There is lots of places where things can go wrong, for starters I would suggest modifying your connection command to invoke a shell without any initialization. Remember to use the `-t` option to force tty allocation. For BASH, the command can look like this:

```
$ ssh -X -p 6623 -t pinker@192.168.0.200 /bin/bash --norc --noprofile
```

Then check the value of `DISPLAY`.