# Directx application using wine over ssh -x

Tags: ssh, x11, ssh-tunneling, wine, directx

I'm trying to run a Windows app (Artemis video game - server mode) on my archlinux server. As it is an windows application I have to run it using Wine.

As I'd like to be able to launch the server from anywhere, I'd like to do it using ssh -X (unfortunatelly this app can only be configured and launched on GUI mode)

I manage to launch wine Artemis.exe on both my laptop (local install) and my server, however launching it using ssh -X gives me an error :

[image]

I'd like to poitn out that ssh -X works fine between those two. I managed to launch "wine notepad" using ssh -X !

It seams to come down to directX, which I don't really know about. I tried installing directX9 through winetricks on both the laptop and the server.

Did anyone face this before ? Have you got any solution for me to try ?

Answer (score 1):

If the server you're `ssh`'ing into has a GUI running you forgo using the `-X` switch to `ssh` and set the `$DISPLAY` variable on the server prior to running the `wine` application like so:

```
$ DISPLAY=:0.0 wine Artemis.exe
```

If on the other hand you do want to see the GUI via `ssh` then you could try changing the compression used to hopefully speed things up via SSH tunnel.

```
$ ssh -c arcfour,blowfish-cbc -X wine Artemis.exe
```

Using these ciphers should significantly speed up your connection.

#### References

[SSH - How to make X applications run on client?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112242/ssh-how-to-make-x-applications-run-on-client/112243#112243)

Comment: I in fact whant to see the GUI via ssh. The compression itself doesn't solve the bug. However I got it working using ssh -Y instead of ssh -X.

Yet, ssh -Y -c arcfour,blowfish-cbc doesn't give efficient result for succesffully forwarding such an application